# How to send a SMS message from within an Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: sms, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to create a Windows Phone 8.1 app that sends the location of the device to a contact in the contact list of the phone via a SMS message. How do I send a SMS message?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Phone 8.1, You can send sms using **ChatMessageManager**:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage msg 
         = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
msg.Body = "This is body of demo message.";
msg.Recipients.Add("10086");
msg.Recipients.Add("10010");
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager
         .ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(msg);
```

There are 2 important params in it: **Body** and **Recipients**.

Body is the content you will send.

Recipients is the contact list who will receive the sms.

Comment: This does not show how to deal with the issues that arise with 'await' and 'async' so I view this as somewhat incomplete--this has been tough to figure out and I'd love a more complete answer if you know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SMS Compose Task to send an SMS message: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394005(v=vs.105).aspx

```
SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();

smsComposeTask.To = "2065550123";
smsComposeTask.Body = "Try this new application. It's great!";

smsComposeTask.Show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 SmsComposeTask SMSCompose = new SmsComposeTask();
 SMSCompose.To = "<Number to which the SMS needs to be sent";
 SMSCompose.Body = "Message that needs to be sent";
 SMSCompose.Show();
```