# ChatMessageManager in Windows Phone 10

Tags: c#, sms, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building an app that composes a SMS and then it uses ChatMessageManager to show the send new sms dialog.
This works just fine in Windows Phone 8.1 but it will not show the SMS dialog in Windows Phone 10.

Anyone who knows if there is a big difference in 8.1 and 10 with that SMS dialog?
Anyone who knows hot to work around it?

Using a code more or less the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900268/1787551

Comment: As far as I know, the Windows Phone 10 SDK has yet to be published, so it's a tad early to ask this kind of question...

Comment: :) Adding, a followup up...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async static Task SendMessage (string phoneNumber)
    {
        ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
        msg.MessageKind = Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageKind.Standard;
        msg.Recipients.Add(phoneNumber);
        await ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(msg);
    }
```

I'm calling the SendMessage method with await, of course. This works for me on Windows 10 Mobile.